# (Proof Check) The set of all algebraic numbers is countable.

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers

Would appreciate if someone could check this proof for me. I'm afraid the wording might be strange. Also don't know if this is correct.

For any $n$ and any $n-$tuple, $(a_0, ..., a_n)$ there are at most $n$ solutions to $a_0x^n + ... + a_n = 0.$ Hence, $n \cdot |\mathbb{Z}^{n + 1}|$ many complex numbers that are roots to $n$th degree polynomials. Call the set of complex numbers that are roots to $n$th degree polynomials $A_n.$ From our last comment, clearly $A_n$ is countable. Hence, the set of all algebraic numbers is $\cup A_n$ which is a countable union of countable sets, hence countable.

Comment: The proof is correct, but in my opinion it's not so good to say "$n \cdot |\mathbb{Z}^{n+1}|$ many complex numbers". While this would denote a countable quantity, it would probably be better to say "countably many".

Comment: Your proof is correct. I am agree with @BaconAndX. You should use the term "countably many".